# NSIS section sizes doubled due to use of SetOverwrite

Tags: nsis

I've inherited an installer script, and I'm annoyed by it claiming to require twice as much space as it actually needs.

I found that this was due to how each section is using `SetOverwrite` (because they're re-used for a repair install?).  I understand that it's necessary to keep the duplicated `File` commands in each of the If/Else blocks because of how `SetOverwrite` works (see below), but I have confirmed that it results in a doubling of the automatic section size calculations.

```
${MementoSection} $(APP_Section_SecHelp) SecHelp
  SetDetailsPrint textonly
  DetailPrint  $(APP_DetailPrint_SecHelp)
  SetDetailsPrint listonly

  SetOutPath $INSTDIR
  SectionIn 1 2
    ${If} $SetOverwriteOn == TRUE
      SetOverwrite ifnewer
      File /r "${APP_SOURCE_DIR}\Help"
    ${Else}
      SetOverwrite off
      File /r "${APP_SOURCE_DIR}\Help"
    ${EndIf}
  SectionGetFlags ${SecHelp} $SecHelp_GetFlag
${MementoSectionEnd}
```

Is this a bad design pattern that I should change?  Do I need to add a hack to call `SectionGetSize`, divide by 2 and call `SectionSetSize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would just use `SetOverwrite ifnewer` for both but if you absolutely want to do it your way then using `SectionSetSize` is one option.

Another thing you could do is to put the repair `File /r` instruction in a separate function that you call from the section. The downside of a function is that the progressbar does not move much during the extraction.

A third alternative is to put some of the repair tasks in a separate section that is unchecked by default and you enable it when you are in repair mode.

*Edit:* Here is a example that uses SectionSetSize:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
InstallDir $Temp
Page Components InitComponentsPage
Page Directory
Page InstFiles  

!macro ModifySectionHack SID TEMPVAR
SectionGetSize ${SID} ${TEMPVAR}
IntOp ${TEMPVAR} ${TEMPVAR} / 2
SectionSetSize ${SID} ${TEMPVAR}
!macroend

Function InitComponentsPage
StrCpy $0 0
loop:
    ClearErrors
    SectionGetFlags $0 $1 ; The error flag is set if we try to access a section that does not exist
    IfErrors done
    !insertmacro ModifySectionHack $0 $1
    IntOp $0 $0 + 1
    Goto loop
done:
FunctionEnd

Section "Foo"
InitPluginsDir ; Need a place to extract to for this example
SetOutPath $PluginsDir

${If} 1 <> 2 ; Don't really care about the result
    SetOverwrite ifnewer
    File "${NSISDIR}\bin\makensis.exe" ; ~400kb
${Else}
    SetOverwrite off
    File "${NSISDIR}\bin\makensis.exe"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd

Section "Bar"
InitPluginsDir ; Need a place to extract to for this example
SetOutPath $PluginsDir

${If} 1 <> 2 ; Don't really care about the result
    SetOverwrite ifnewer
    File "${NSISDIR}\nsis.exe" ; ~700kb
${Else}
    SetOverwrite off
    File "${NSISDIR}\nsis.exe"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

This loops through all the sections and adjusts all of them but I'm not sure if that is such a good idea. If this was my script then I would manually call ModifySectionHack on each section that has the SetOverwrite problem:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
InstallDir $Temp
Page Components
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

!macro ModifySectionHack SID TEMPVAR
SectionGetSize ${SID} ${TEMPVAR}
IntOp ${TEMPVAR} ${TEMPVAR} / 2
SectionSetSize ${SID} ${TEMPVAR}
!macroend

Section "Foo" SID_FOO
InitPluginsDir ; Need a place to extract to for this example
SetOutPath $PluginsDir

${If} 1 <> 2 ; Don't really care about the result
    SetOverwrite ifnewer
    File "${NSISDIR}\bin\makensis.exe" ; ~400kb
${Else}
    SetOverwrite off
    File "${NSISDIR}\bin\makensis.exe"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd

Section "Bar"
${If} 1 = 2
  File /r "${NSISDIR}\stubs"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd

Section "Baz" SID_BAZ
InitPluginsDir ; Need a place to extract to for this example
SetOutPath $PluginsDir

${If} 1 <> 2 ; Don't really care about the result
    SetOverwrite ifnewer
    File "${NSISDIR}\nsis.exe" ; ~700kb
${Else}
    SetOverwrite off
    File "${NSISDIR}\nsis.exe"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd

Function .onInit
; Adjust the section size for the sections that use SetOverwrite:
!insertmacro ModifySectionHack ${SID_FOO} $1
!insertmacro ModifySectionHack ${SID_BAZ} $1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: I'd love to see an example of using `SectionSetSize`.  Can I embed that in each section, or do I need to script it somewhere else to cycle through a list of section names getting the size, dividing by 2, and then setting the size?  I have limited experience with NSIS, and don't want to hack a solution together that might not be reliable.

Comment: You have to use SectionSetSize before you get to a place where it is visible in the UI. The pre callback for the components page is a good place but if you need the adjusted section sizes in other places you might want to put it in .onInit instead.